# Distributional representation of a function defined at a single point

Tags: physics, distribution-theory

During some calculation regarding a physics problem, I came across a function, which we will denote as $u(x)$, which is $1/2$ if $x=y$, where $y$ is a positive real number, and $0$ elsewhere. Since I then have to integrate this function $u$, I need a suitable representation in order to do the actual calculation.
To give a little bit of context, the function $u$ derive from the time-average of the product of two trigonometric functions at different frequencies. In particular,

$$ \langle \cos (x t - \phi) \, \cos (y t - \phi') \rangle := \lim_{T\rightarrow+\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} dt \, \cos (x t - \phi) \, \cos (y t - \phi') $$

The time-average is $\ne 0$ only when the frequencies are the same, and so here's where $u$ comes from. Now, I know that, in the "discrete" case, i.e. when $x$ and $y$ are integers, the time average is proportional to the Kroneker delta $\delta_{x,y}$. However, in this case $x$ and $y$ are continuous variables. My "physical" guess is that the Kronecker delta becomes a Dirac delta, but, since $\delta (x-y)$ have the dimension of the inverse of a frequency and the result must be dimensionless, we have to multiply with something that have dimension of a frequency. Thus, I was expecting something proportional to $y \, \delta (x-y)$. This is a very heuristic argument; and I need something more precise. For istance, while doing some research, I learned that every distribution $v$ defined at a single point $y$ can be represented, if I understand correctly, as

$$ v(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} c_n (y) \, \delta^{(n)} (x-y) \, ,$$

where $N$ is called the order of the distribution $v$, $c_n$ are constants (that I guess depend on the point at which $v$ is defined) and $\delta^{(n)} (x-y)$ is the $n$-th derivative of the Dirac distribution. Unfortunately, my knowledge of distribution theory is pretty basic, and I can't quite understand how to determine the degree $N$ and the constants $c_n $ associated to the function $u$. Any help would be very, very appreciated. Also, if the problem can be solved without explicitly determining $N$ and $c_n $, this kind of solution if obviously welcome.

I thank you in advance, and I apologize if such a question already exists without me having found it on the website.

Comment: Hi. I'm a bit confused by your question. If $u$ is defined by $u(y) = 1/2$ and $\forall x\neq y,\, u(x) = 0$, then $\int u(x)dx = 0$. No "representation" is going to change the fact that the integral of $u$ is zero. In particular, this function $u$ is not the Dirac delta. If the integral of $u$ is not zero, then $u$ is not the function defined above.

Comment: I think this can be put as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u$ is really defined by $u(y) = 1/2$ and $\forall x\neq y,\, u(x) = 0$, then $$\int u(x)dx = 0.$$

No "representation" is going to change the fact that the integral of $u$ is zero. In particular, this function $u$ is not the Dirac delta.

If the integral of $u$ is not zero, then $u$ is not the function defined above.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I feel quite silly for not having seen before that, the way I posed the problem, the integral was inevitably zero. Maybe the fact that the final result should be different from zero and the tiredness of the last few days of always dealing with the same things has clouded my judgment. I probably need to review the steps that led me to this point. Anyway, thank you again for your time

Comment: @luta_naccarata If you ask another question on the same topic, do not hesitate to leave a comment here so I see it! The mathematical way to deal with Dirac delta is to say that it is a distribution but not a function, because "0 almost-everywhere" and "integral equal to 1 in the neighbourhood of zero" are contradictory for a function. Distributions are a very natural generalisation of functions, so physicists often calls them functions and don't bother with the distinction; still, the fact that u is defined at every point is a bit too precise to allow it to have a non-zero integral.